# Facebook Realtime Updates for Payments callback POST received but still having issues

Tags: facebook, callback, payment, updates

I am using Facebook payments and Realtime Updates for Payments. Here is a typical payment callback from Facebook servers when someone buys/refunds something:

```
{
  "object": "payments",
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": "296989303750203",
      "time": 1347996346,
      "changed_fields": [
        "actions"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using PHP to get this like this:

```
$updates = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

It works ok and I got the id stored in `$myid`. My problem is:

In the same PHP page I try to get details of this ID but it doesn't work:

```
$getDetails = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$myid.'?access_token='.$app_token));
```

The response is empty, nothing there. I even tried to get the user with this `$user = $facebook->getUser();` in this PHP but it returned with zero. I suspect that since this PHP is run from the Facebook server (and not the client browser) Facebook does not know who the user is and that is why the Graph API does not work.

How can this PHP page knows who the user is? Cookies and sessions cannot be used since they will never communicate with the client browser. Help is needed. Thanks.

Comment: `file_get_contents` doesn’t tell you if anything goes wrong with an HTTP request by default. Why don’t you just use the PHP SDK to make API calls …?

Comment: I Will try that now ans see what I get.